# How do I unlock the Story mode?

Tags: magic-the-gathering-puzzle-quest

I just started playing MTG Puzzle Quest, and I still haven't unlocked story mode. I've leveled up Nissa to level 12 just by doing Quick Battles thinking that might do it, but no luck. **So what do I have to do to unlock the Story mode?**

Comment: ... Not sure. For me, the story mode was unlocked and available immediately after I was done the tutorial levels.

Comment: I've submitted a ticket. I will update this if anything significant is revealed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apparently this is a known issue with the game. In fact, two issues:

1. Players being locked out of Story Mode after completing the
   tutorial.
2. Support tickets sent from the app itself are not reaching
   the appropriate end points.

As a result, [open a ticket by going to this address directly](http://www.d3go.com/mobile-games-support) instead of using the app. When I did this, they were able to unblock me within a couple hours.